# Custom annotations not loading into array?

Tags: ios, annotations

Below is my code for loading my custom annotations into an array and then adding this array to my map using addAnnotations.  I am not getting any pins on my map. If I replace `[annotations addObject:annotation];` with `[annotations addObject:item.placemark];` I get pins but they are not my custom annotations. I have a customAnnotation class called Annotation. What am I doing wrong?

```
NSMutableArray *annotations = [NSMutableArray array];

                [response.mapItems enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(MKMapItem *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

                    // if we already have an annotation for this MKMapItem,
                    // just return because you don't have to add it again

                    for (id<MKAnnotation>annotation in mapView.annotations)
                    {
                        if (annotation.coordinate.latitude == item.placemark.coordinate.latitude &&
                            annotation.coordinate.longitude == item.placemark.coordinate.longitude)
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                    }


                    // otherwise add it

                    Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] initWithPlacemark:item.placemark];
                    annotation.title = mapItem.name;
                    annotation.subtitle = mapItem.placemark.addressDictionary[(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
                    [annotations addObject:annotation];

 [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotations];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, quite simply, can only be (a) problem adding the annotations; or (b) problem showing the annotations. I suspected the former initially (given your weird indentation, I suspected you might have some problem with some asynchronous call you didn't share with us), but given that you say that it works fine if you use the placemark instead of the annotation, I have to suspect the problem must rest in the showing of the annotations (namely `viewForAnnotation`).

I'd first suggest you do some diagnostic work. You can confirm whether annotations are being added properly by logging the `count` of `self.mapView.annotations` before and after the `addAnnotations` call. I'd suspect (based upon what you've said) you'll see the count go up.

I would then take a look at `viewForAnnotation`, and make sure it's handling your `Annotation` class properly. Frequently we have `if ([annotation isKindOfClass:...)` logic, so maybe you have some issue there. It's hard to say on the basis of the small snippet of code shared with us.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and helping me break down the logic behind the problem.

Comment: hmmm. Well now I get the strangest behaviour.  When I make the change I mentioned it fixes the annotation problem...but now when I try to tap my back button ( which dismisses the viewcontroller) my app crashes. I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x4).

Comment: @user1639594 That's frustrating, I'm sure, but we don't have enough here to diagnose what's going on. I'd try turning on [exception breakpoints](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) and see if that helps identify the offending code. If not, put your own breakpoints in your code and then single step through candidate routines and see if you can identify which line is causing the problem. If worst comes to worst, feel free to upload the project somewhere and I can take a look.